# Massive CSV to MySQL import issue

Tags: mysql, csv, import

**The issue:** The CSV data, received from my warehouse, has over 2 million+ numbers I need to import into a [single column] in a [multicolumn] table. I need to figure out how to import a CSV file into MySQL, but there are some tricky issues to overcome. After some research, I haven't found a solution yet...

The columns can be laid out as such: (this data does not exist in the database yet)

- **id:** autoincremented value
- **serialCode:** value gotten from CSV
- **somethingID:** assigned to another table ID value

  ```
   ID  | serialCode | somethingID 
  --------------------------------
    1  |  1234567   |      42    
    2  |  2345678   |      21  
    3  |  3456789   |      14
  ```

The 2 million+ serial numbers come to me as in the example format below. Each number is a separate serialCode, separated by a comma, with 4 serialCodes in one row.

```
7121316,8216697,5146909,5191409,
8125250,6217542,5144896,8198066,
3125654,9217139,2146880,1192013
```

**What I need to do** is INSERT these serial codes into the MySQL database, specifically into the serialCode column ONLY. The ID will auto increment, and the somethingID will be assigned at a later date.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL's `LOAD DATA INFILE` command will be your friend here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html

Create the table first then I think the following command should work:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/path/to/file" INTO TABLE myTable LINES TERMINATED BY "," (serialCode) SET ID=NULL;
```

Comment: Couple of issues with the answer. First, I get an error message: **unknown column 'serialCode' in 'field List'** BUT the column is truly named that including case-sensitive letters. Second, I believe the code you provided will have issues because fields may need to be terminated with the ",". Here is my code: `$loadsql = 'LOAD DATA INFILE "'.$csvfile.'" INTO TABLE '.$table.' FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" (serialCode) SET ID=NULL;`

Comment: btw...I tried your code, it gave the error message I mentioned above.

Comment: Got it to work! Here's the proper code `$loadsql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" .$csvfile."' INTO TABLE ".$table." FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (serialcode) SET id=NULL;";`

Comment: Ike's answer below is correct and works around the "\n" issue. Your "Got it to work!" query definitely doesn't work.

Comment: yeah, my bad...it only inserted in the first row

Comment: To be sure it worked run this commandn from the MySQL console (or phpmyadmin if you have that installed) so you can see if any warnings were generated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) for this. The tricky part is that your line terminator is sometimes a comma, but sometimes it's a comma and a line break.

The easiest way around this is to load the values into a user variable, and then strip the line breaks from the user variable when you set the actual column variable in the table.

Something like this should work for you:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/your_file.csv'
INTO TABLE your_table
LINES TERMINATED BY ','
(@serialCode)
SET id = NULL,
   serialCode = REPLACE(@serialCode,'\n','');
```

Comment: If the file has windows line endings as suggested with "\r\n" then just modify the '\n' in this solution to '\r\n'

Comment: James C, your answer completes this issue. The insert process is now successful. Note* if one does not add the \r command, then the code inserts a 0 into the new field line.

Answer (score 0):

If mysql tool fail for whatever reason (memory limitations, encoding issues, invalid csv) you always have the option to write a script in your preferred programming language to parse and store the contents of the csv into the DB. Most programming languages have csv parsing abilities.